# How to create a class in java which instance cannot be created?

Tags: java, class, instance

I have to create a class. Instance of this class cannot be made. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean an interface or abstract class?

Comment: Just normal class like:  public class Class{...}

Comment: This is an acceptable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859137/if-i-do-not-want-to-instantiate-a-class-what-are-my-options

Answer (score 5):

Declare it abstract and add a private constructor.

Comment: If you wish to use it as a singleton, you can also add a getInstance method that can always return the same instance handled as a static field in the class itself. This will work if the class is not abstract of course.

Comment: Class must be abstract? And what should be in this constructor(I dont need any)?

Comment: @Pawel if class will not be `abstract` you will be able to instantiate it via reflection (even with private constructor). If constructor will not be private then it could be used outside of that class (like by class in same package).

Comment: Nothing should be in the constructor. Just declare : private MyAbsClass() { // Empty private constructor; } and that's all. It's just to make it more or less invisible ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean no instances can ever be made? or just one instance?

If no instances can ever be made, then make the class final with a private constructor.  All methods then need to be static.  A good example of this is [java.lang.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

If you need only a single instance and want no one else to make new instances, then consider using an enum as described in *Effective Java 2nd ed*:

```
public enum MyClass{

   INSTANCE;


  ...methods
}
```

Code that uses this class then invokes methods like this: `MyClass.INSTANCE.foo()`.

Comment: I dont want any instances of it. Class must be final?

Comment: if there is a private constructor then no one can subclass it anyway but might as well make it final as well as an additional hint to the users (and compiler)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to instantiate that class then I assume that you only want it to have some static methods. In that case you can easily do it with `enum` with no constants like

```
enum MyUtilities{
    ;//if you want you can place instances of that class here, or not place any

    //your methods
    public static void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: It has to be a class.

Comment: Enum is a class... special one, but still class.