# If I do not want to instantiate a class, what are my options?

Tags: java, instantiation

I have a class with all static methods which basically makes calls like `ClassName#MethodName()`.

I want this class to be non-instantiable at all times and so I have set the constructor visibility to be `private`. This certainly avoids any instance of it being created from outside the class. 
I want to know if there is any technical term coined or any design pattern specifically designed for doing exactly this which I do not know of.

Also this does not stop me or any other developer from instantiating it from within the same class. I want to know if it is possible to prevent doing that but keeping the same class behavior. Also, what are the other options, if any?

Comment: An abstract class can be subclassed, and the subclass can be instantiated, so this isn't a good solution. Josh Bloch covers this in his book Effective Java. He says that _utility classes_ should explicitly implement a private constructor, and have that constructor throw an AssertionError. There's no need to make the class final because the private constructor will prevent any class from extending it.

Comment: What about a `private static abstract class Test {}`?

Comment: Static when used on a class doesn't have the same meaning in Java that it has in other languages like C#. You can still subclass the abstract class and instantiate the subclass.

Comment: sbat's comment would be the answer. Properly document it as an `Utility` class (& the constructor) so that no developer working on it would instantiate it.

Comment: I guess disabling instantiation from outside is enough. Somebody modifying the code of the class itself can always do whatever he wants (including the removal of any safeguards).

Comment: Why a downvote? What part is not clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just use an `enum`  The class is made `final`, it's constructors `private` and it is not instancable even via reflection.

```
public enum Utility {;
    public static void staticMethod() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Using an `enum` allows you define all possible instance of a class and in this cause you have defined there can't be any.

Comment: Just want to point out that there is a semi colon after the first brace which is required so that java knows that there are no values for the enum. I almost missed it when trying it out myself

Comment: @Peter It's a different option for sure! However it doesn't serve the purpose of an enum as you mentioned and may lead to an incorrect pattern being used.

Comment: @gsndev IMHO on balance, it will save more errors than it will create.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am confused when you say you use an `enum` and make `class` final. Can you please elaborate or extend your example? Also how are you controlling the instance creation here? Will it be an answer to the question if I said I need exactly 2 instances?

Comment: @Prince an `enum` is a `final` class. In an `enum` you list all the object you want to create which can be zero, one (called a Singleton), two or many.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks! I just got it after reading your [blog](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2010/08/two-uses-for-enum-most-people-forget.html). Funny, you didn't point to that link. :)

Answer (score 4):

i would write like:

```
public class MyClass{
// Suppress default constructor for noninstantiability
    private MyClass(){
          throw new AssertionError();
    }
          . . . . . 
          . . . . . 
          . . . . . 
}
```

Because the explicit constructor is `private`, it is inaccessible outside of the class. The `AssertionError` isn’t strictly required, but it provides insurance in case the constructor is accidentally invoked from within the class. It guarantees that the class will never be instantiated under any circumstances. This idiom is mildly counterintuitive, as the constructor is provided expressly so that it cannot be invoked. It is therefore wise to include a comment, as shown above.

[source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683).

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach is using the `private` constructor as you said:

```
public final class MyClass {    

    private MyClass() {}

    public static void do() {}
}
```

and also make it `final` so no one can extend your class.

Answer (score 2):

Make the constructor private and the class final.